# How can I find who made a commit with a specific SHA, who doesn't have 7 digits?

Tags: git

I have this part of this SHA : f9720a. So I want to find who made this commit, using the function git log. How am I able to do that?

Comment: In gitk you can search on the SHA.

Comment: `git log --format="format:%H %an" | grep f9720a`

Answer (score 0):

`format`, allows you to specify your own log output format.This is especially useful when you’re generating output for machine parsing — because you specify the format explicitly, you know it won’t change with updates to Git:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H - %an
f9720a- steve mohammmad
```

`%h`--Abbreviated commit hash `or` `%H`--commit hash

`%an`--Author name

Comment: The assumption here is that the SHA _begins_ with these digits, which may not be what OP wants.

Comment: is it ok now ??

Comment: No, you're still only considering the short hash (first _n_ digits). The correct placeholder should be  `%H`. Then you can `grep` through it. Basically exactly like my comment 

Comment: msbit I forgot to say, but yes, this begins with f9720a. I've put your answer in the goto of the Gitk, and then returns to me that is not known. Did you find it in your gitk?

Answer (score 0):

If:

- `f9720a` is a *prefix* of the full commit hash ID, and
- `f9720a` is *unique* as a such a prefix—that is, no other commit hash ID starts with `f9720a`

then:

```
git show f9720a^{commit}
```

suffices.<sup>1</sup>

If this is a non-unique prefix, or not a prefix at all, you'll have to find all commits whose hash ID *contains* `f9720a` and inspect each one, as each one could be the commit in question.

In all cases *you must have this commit in your Git repository*.  If you never have had this commit, you cannot inspect it: you must first *get* the commit from some Git repository that *does* have it.

The probability that some partial hash ID matches multiple commits depends on the number of commits.  While each full commit hash ID occurs 1 out of 2<sup>160</sup> times, each six-character prefix occurs 1 out of 2<sup>24</sup> times.  Those might seem like good odds, but the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) means that 24 bits is not enough in a lot of medium-to-large repositories.  Even seven characters (28 bits) is still not enough.  That's why Git uses 40 characters (160 bits).

---

<sup>1</sup>In Windows CMD, be sure to double the `^` character.  In some shells (e.g., tcsh) you may need other quoting methods.

Comment: I believe you can use `~` in place of `^` under Windows

Comment: @msbit: you can use `~` with or without a numeric suffix to count back 1 or N steps from the resolved thing that comes before the tilde: e.g., `master~3` means *resolve `master`, then count back 3 first-parent hops*. But this is only a valid substitute for suffix `^` that means "first parent": it's not allowed for the `{...}` syntax.